# How to auto submit the suggested value from the autocomplete jQuery script?

Tags: php, jquery

Below there is my code that shows a suggested list of words (rpc.php) when the user type 3 and more letters in the textbox. My question is how can I edit it, that when the user select a suggested word, the form is submitted?

Now when I click on a suggested word it places it in the textbox.

I thought of two possible ways.

1. The form is auto submitted when the user selects a suggested word.
2. The suggested word is a link that gets you correctly to the results page. (I can set the desired link through the rpc.php).

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $().ready(function() {

       $("#s").autocomplete("rpc.php", {
           width: 250,
           selectFirst: false,
           minChars: 3,
           scroll:true,
           matchContains: true,
           scrollHeight: 250
       });

   });
   </script>
   ```

this is my form

```
<form method="get" action=".php">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="inputsearch">
<input id="searchform" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This would be very easy with the jQueryUI version of this plugin (http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete). This plugin has been deprecated in favor of that one. Is upgrading to that plugin an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#s").autocomplete("rpc.php", {
        width: 250,
        selectFirst: false,
        minChars: 3,
        scroll:true,
        matchContains: true,
        scrollHeight: 250
    }).result(function(event, item) {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.php",
            data: {s:$("#s").val()},
            success: function(msg){
                 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                     }
            });
    });
```

Comment: because I am not very familiar with ajax and jQuery how can I send the value of my textbox with name and id s ? I have updated my question with the form.

Comment: Thanks for this, I get a response but what I want is to take him to a page as this www.domain.com/index.php?s= AND THE SUGGESTED WORD. Is that possible ?

Comment: make url something like this url: "www.domain.com/index.php?s="+$("#s").val()